# React Hooks. Pass value as argument to useReducer()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

It is my first time using useReducer() hook and I am facing a problem where I need to pass it a value as argument.

Here is how my reducer looks like:

```
  const memoizedReducer = useCallback((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "save":
        const refreshedBookData = {
          ...state.bookData,
          ...(state.bookData.totalSaves >= 0 && {
            totalSaves: state.bookData.totalSaves + 1,
          }),
          isSaved: true,
        };
       
        // Add the new book data to a Map which I have in a Context provider
        currentUser.addBookToVisitedBooks(bookId, refreshedBookData);
        
        // Update my context provider data
        currentUser.setData((prevCurrentUserData) => {
          return {
            ...prevCurrentUserData,
            ...(prevCurrentUserData.totalSaves >= 0 && {
              totalSaves: prevCurrentUserData.totalSaves + 1,
            }),
          };
        });
        
        return refreshedBookData;

    case "unsave":
        const refreshedBookData = {
          ...state.bookData,
          ...(state.otheBookData.totalSaves >= 0 && {
            totalSaves: state.bookData.totalSaves - 1,
          }),
          isSaved: false,
        };

        // Add the new book data to a Map which I have in a Context provider
        currentUser.addBookToVisitedBooks(bookId, refreshedBookData);
      
        // Update my context provider data
        currentUser.setData((prevCurrentUserData) => {
          return {
            ...prevCurrentUserData,
            ...(prevCurrentUserData.totalSaves > 0 && {
              totalSaves: prevCurrentUserData.totalSaves - 1,
            }),
          };
        });
        
        return refreshedBookData;
      
    default:
        return state;
});


const [{ bookData }, dispatch] = useReducer(memoizedReducer, {
   bookData: params?.bookData
});
```

As you can see, what I am doing is:

1- If the action type is "save", increase the total saves for the book, add the new book data to a Map of "visitedBooks" which I have in a Context (ignore this part), and update my currentUser data increasing his total saves.

2- If the action type is "unsave", I do the opposite.

My problem is that I need to pass an argument "reviews" to the reducer. For example, if I have this function for fetching "extra data" from my db:

```
   const fetchReviews = async (bookId) => {
       // Get a list of reviews from the db
       const reviews = await db.fetchReviews(bookId);

       return reviews;
   }
```

and I use it like this:

```
  const reviews = await fetchReviews(bookId);
```

how can I pass the reviews as argument to the reducer?

```
  dispatch({ type: saved ? "save" : "unsave" });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already pass down an object to `dispatch()` and nothing stops you to add a `payload` along with the `type`:

```
dispatch({ 
  type: saved ? "save" : "unsave",
  payload: reviews,
});
```

This way you can access the reviews in your reducer (`action.payload`).

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  // action has `type` and `payload` properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And one more thing, something that is more about your personal opinion, is it advisable to generalize the code of similar useReducer actions?

Answer (score 3):

When you call the `dispatch` method, you're passing an object which has the `type` field. The format of this object is actually up to you to define. If you need to pass parameters other than `type` you can freely do so.

For example

```js
const reviews = {....} ; /// reviews  
dispatch({ type: 'save', payload: reviews });
```

Then in your reducer you can you the `payload` object

```js
// Reducer 

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'save':
            const reviews = action.payload;
            //.....
            break;
    }
}
```

I suggest reading this article https://redux.js.org/basics/actions